# How to use key bindings in Godot from C++ extension code?

Tags: c++, godot

I have created a simple C++ "game" in godot. Lacking any good documentation, I based my work off examples on the internet, and for input I have this:

```
    const Input* i = Input::get_singleton();

    double delta_v = 0;
    if (i->is_action_pressed("ui_up"))
        delta_v += acceleration * delta;
    if (i->is_action_pressed("ui_down"))
        delta_v -= acceleration * delta;
    if (i->is_action_pressed("ui_left"))
        angular_velocity -= angular_acceleration * delta;
    if (i->is_action_pressed("ui_right"))
        angular_velocity += angular_acceleration * delta;
```

Based on that, I wanted to add a new action triggered by space. So I tried this:

```
    const Input* i = Input::get_singleton();
    if (i->is_action_pressed("game_shoot"))
    {
        
    }
```

I then added this action in the project key mapping:

[image]

But I am getting an error:

```
The InputMap action "game_shoot" doesn't exist.
```

Curiously, it works from a script like this:

```
func _input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("game_shoot"):
        print("game_shoot occurred!")
```

Comment: How have you configured your [Input Map](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_inputmap.html#class-inputmap), as [described in the documentation here](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/inputs/input_examples.html#input-map)?

Comment: @DMGregory Not really, thanks for the link. But if configuration is required, how come the arrows work out of the box?

Comment: I'd guess because they're pre-configured as commonly-used defaults? I've never used Godot, but Unity does something similar with both the legacy Input Manager and the new Input System package.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks, I understand now. However adding new action, such as `game_shoot` does not seem to work. I am still getting the same error when I try to query it from the C++ side.

Comment: Make sure you edit your question to show your updated configuration and code.

Comment: @DMGregory I edited it. It looks like there is something broken in the C++ bindings, because this does work with scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out. There is a method on the `InputMap` singleton. You probably should call this only once.

```
    InputMap* map = InputMap::get_singleton();
    map->load_from_project_settings();
```